# Terraform reapply creates duplicate resources

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am new to terraform and I would like to understand how I can prevent resources from duplications while doing terraform reapply.

Scenario here is, I have created all the necessary resources for the very first time doing terraform apply. However later I had few additional resources added and when I do terraform apply (again) I see my VPC is getting duplicated which eventually duplicates subnets, route tables and network connections.

MyDemoVPC VPC is created once again when I reapply terraform, how do I prevent resources from  duplication. Kindly help me on this issue.

```
resource "aws_vpc" "demo" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    Name = "MyDemoVPC"
  }
}

resource "aws_vpc_dhcp_options" "demo" {
  domain_name         = "demo.com"
  domain_name_servers = ["10.0.0.1", "AmazonProvidedDNS"]
  ntp_servers         = ["192.168.0.1"]

  tags = {
    Name = "Demo VPC"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you do not persist the [state](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state) anywhere and start from scratch each time.

Comment: how did you define the TF state?

Comment: @luk2302 and Nico Marino thanks for insights on this topic. I did not define anything in TF state. Basically each time there was a change the existing directory where the terraform lies is deleted which eventually deletes all the meta-data directories. So, new resources are created every time terraform apply is issued. I understand that this directory should not be deleted otherwise duplicates will get created. Thanks to both of you, I was able to get much needed understanding on this topic.

Comment: thanks @MarkAndrew! this explains everything!